# Запятые корректны?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**В нашем районе открылась новая творческая студия, где такие, как я, начинающие художники-любители могут раскрыть свои таланты.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант редактирования:

*В нашем районе открылась новая творческая студия, где **начинающие** художники-любители, **такие как я**, могут раскрыть свои таланты.*

**Пояснение**

Здесь оборот "такие как я" обособляется как единое целое.

Правило: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_722

...в некоторых случаях запятая ставится не перед словом «как», а перед словом «такой»:

1. если слова «такой как» соотносятся **с предшествующим прилагательным**: Погода дождливая, такая как осенью. Обстановка в этом доме была мрачная, такая как в старинных замках.

Также материалы из Интернета: https://popravilam.com/blog/161-takie-kak.html
Пример: Некоторые ученики, такие как Вася и Петя, поставят запятую…

Answer (score 1):

С такой пунктуацией смысл такой:
*...где такие, как я, **и** начинающие художники-любители могут раскрыть свои таланты.*

Не хватает запятой перед "могут", тогда смысл будет верным.